# Remove a manually installed driver (wireless usb)

Tags: wifi, drivers, usb, proprietary-drivers

I downloaded and installed a driver for my wireless usb dongle as it wasn't detected by linux (KDE). I wasn't very sure which model it was but apparently it is a Ralink RT2870 (Brand name IPTime N150UA).
I downloaded the driver, patched a file to make it compatible with my new kernel version (3 and above) following [this page](http://www.arnelborja.com/compiling-rt2870-wifi-driver-in-fedora/) and finally installed it like shown in the page.
Then My wifi dongle was detected and I could connect to the network. The problem is, as soon as I do ssh or open the router's webpage my whole computer freezes and I have to shut it down.
Now I want to delete this driver, I searched on internet but couldn't find anything helpful. When I run lshw I get for my wireless driver:

> description: Wireless interface
>   physical id: 1
>   logical name:
>   ra0
>   serial: 64:e5:99:f6:33:60
>   capabilities: ethernet physical
>   wireless
>   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=RALINK WLAN ip=192.168.1.8 multicast=yes wireless=Ralink STA

That is a very weird driver name with a space in the middle. I can't even follow some tutorials about how to get more information about a driver because when I input RALINK WLAN it thinks it is two different driver names.
What should I do?

Comment: What distribution are you using?

Answer (score 5):

According to your [link](http://www.arnelborja.com/compiling-rt2870-wifi-driver-in-fedora/) the filename of the driver should be `mt7601Usta.ko` (`.ko` is the extension for kernel modules).

Kernel modules are usually installed in `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)`, so use `find /lib/modules/$(uname -r) -name mt7601Usta.ko` then `sudo rm` to delete it if you're sure it is the right module (or `mv` to move it out from the modules tree so it won't be loaded on next boot).

But probably you'll need to unload the module before.

You can use `lsmod` command to see currently loaded modules and `rmmod` to unload a module for the current session (it would be loaded again on next boot), names from `lsmod` doesn't always correspond to filenames.

With `lsmod` results you can use `modinfo` command to get informations about the module (ie: `modinfo <modulename>`)

Depending on the distro you're using you may be able to *blacklist* adding a line in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` so it won't be loaded on boot

```
blacklist mt7601Usta
```

Add a new file if `blacklist.conf` doesn't exist

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "blacklist mt7601Usta" >/etc/modprobe.d/no-mt7601Usta.conf'
```

You can also *blacklist* it from the kernel command line (ie: grub bootloader)

```
modprobe.blacklist=mt7601Usta
```

Answer (score 0):

Look in the 'Makefile' of the driver source you downloaded. It will have a block named 'install', which will look something like this:

```
install: #dependencies
    #some stuff
    #some more stuff
```

If you typed `make some_keyword` to install the driver, look for the block starting with 'some_keyword' instead of 'install'

The commands in this block were executed when you typed `make install` and then entered your password. This block will have some commands which moved the driver files from the compilation directory to some other directories, most probably to somewhere in '/usr/lib' find those commands and delete all the mentioned files.

You can execute `grep 'mv ' Makefile'` to easily find those commands. This although assumes that the makefile is named 'Makefile', not 'makefile' or something else.

The point is that the commands which actually modified your system were in the install block of the makefile, the one for which you had to give root permission. All the rest are compilation instructions.